# MAUI .Net Bindings stopped Working after the last Preview Update. Where is my Mistake?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, binding, maui

To be honest I am kinda lost.
I am currently developping a medium sized app with .Net MAUI, I was almost done but after the update to Visual Studio 17.3.0 Preview 2.0 my Bindings stopped working.
I am using MVVM with the Microsoft.Toolkit.MVVM, CommunityToolkit.MAUI and DI.

As I said the Bindings worked before how they are here.
All Guides I could find did basically the same thing as me.
I have no Idea why it wouldn't work how I have it set up.

The function in the Command gets executed and the value changes when I Debug it and the PropertyChanged Event gets called... but the Binding is not working the Label stays Hidden. It also is Hidden all the time when I initialize "IsWorking" as "True".

If anyone has Ideas or notices a Mistake please help me out.

My basic Setup looks like this:

"MauiProgram.cs" Where i set up the DI.

```
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder.UseMauiApp<App>().UseMauiCommunityToolkit();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

        // DI
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPageViewModel>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

"MainPage.xaml.cs Code Behind" The BindingContext gets Set.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    // Gets ViewModel with DI
    public MainPage(MainPageViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Set ViewModel as BindingContext
        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

"MainPage.xaml" The Basic new Project Page with a Command and a Binding

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="MauiApp2.MainPage">
             
    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout 
            Spacing="25" 
            Padding="30,0" 
            VerticalOptions="Center">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                
            <Label 
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                IsVisible="{Binding IsWorking}"/>
            
            <Label 
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button 
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Command="{Binding ClickedCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
 
</ContentPage>
```

"MainPageViewModel.cs" Viewmodel with Property thas bound and the Command

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MauiApp2
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ObservableObject
    {
        public IRelayCommand ClickedCommand { get; set; }


        private bool _isWorking;

        public bool IsWorking
        {
            get { return _isWorking; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _isWorking, value); }
        }

        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            ClickedCommand = new RelayCommand(Clicked);
            IsWorking = false;
        }

        private void Clicked() 
        {
            if (IsWorking)
                IsWorking = false;
            else
                IsWorking = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I tested some more and I think it has something to do with the way the UI is renderd. If the element was visible long enough or after I change the Orientation of the Device it will work. If the thing is hidden or gets hidden to quickly the space for the element is never created so it does not show even if it is Visible. Binding isn't the Issue as far as I can tell.